# OpenTok iOS API:Stream in iPad more then two

Tags: ios, stream, opentok

I want to make live streaming for more then two users on different devices  and get api from opentok i had download demo app from ( https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-iOS-Hello-World) and this is not webrtc, i had run application with key, session and token with disables of pear to pear,
 And its working fine for two live streaming but while i tray to connect third stream i am not able to getting that,
 I found staring in demo app that (On iPad 2 / 3 / 4, the limit is four streams. An app can have up to four simultaneous subscribers, or one publisher and up to three subscribers.)

with this i am testing with three iPads and got just two on screen

so how to make this more then two stream at a time in three iPads

Answer (score 1):

The project you linked (OpenTok-iOS-Hello-World) is built to just subscribe to one stream. Just as a proof of concept, you can get two subscribers on screen pretty simply by just modifying a few methods and adding an instance variable in `ViewController.m`

Create a variable that tracks the number of subscribers:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    OTSession* _session;
    OTPublisher* _publisher;
    OTSubscriber* _subscriber;
    int _numSubscribers;  // **NEW**
}
```

Initialize the variable in the initialization method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _session = [[OTSession alloc] initWithSessionId:kSessionId
                                           delegate:self];
    _numSubscribers = 0;  // **NEW**
    [self doConnect];
}
```

Make sure we aren't subscribing to our own stream:

```
static bool subscribeToSelf = NO;
```

Modify stop caring about whether there is already a subscriber in this session delegate method:

```
- (void)session:(OTSession*)mySession didReceiveStream:(OTStream*)stream
{
    NSLog(@"session didReceiveStream (%@)", stream.streamId);

    // See the declaration of subscribeToSelf above.
    if ( (subscribeToSelf && [stream.connection.connectionId isEqualToString: _session.connection.connectionId])
           ||
         (!subscribeToSelf && ![stream.connection.connectionId isEqualToString: _session.connection.connectionId])
       ) {
        // ** Changing if statement **
        if (_numSubscribers < 2) {
            _subscriber = [[OTSubscriber alloc] initWithStream:stream delegate:self];
            _numSubscribers++;
        }
    }
}
```

Place the subscribers next to one another, taking up a little less width:

```
- (void)subscriberDidConnectToStream:(OTSubscriber*)subscriber
{
    NSLog(@"subscriberDidConnectToStream (%@)", subscriber.stream.connection.connectionId);
    // ** Calculate the frame **
    CGRect subFrame = CGRectMake(0, widgetHeight, widgetWidth / 2, widgetHeight)
    if (_numSubscribers == 2) subFrame = CGRectOffset(subFrame, widgetWidth / 2, 0);
    [subscriber.view setFrame:subFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:subscriber.view];
}
```

NOTE: This solution doesn't result in a stable App. It should get you to a point where you can see both subscribers as long as you don't disconnect any of the iPads in between. To finish this off, you will need to store the OTSubscribers created in `session:didRecieveStream:` in a collection like NSArray, handle removing the right subscriber(s) and decrementing the `_numSubscribers` in `session:didDropStream:`, and thinking about how you want the `updateSubscriber` method to work instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for hello world in the [viewcontroller file line 93](https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-iOS-Hello-World/blob/master/OpenTokHelloWorld/ViewController.m#L93), you will see that it is only creating one subscriber. To have multiple subscribers simple create an array or hash object to store multiple subscribers.